# Sell photos through Wordpress

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I have an existing photo blog, which displays photos with width of 670 pixels.

I'd like to sell higher resolution photos from the same page the lower resolution photo is displayed.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I'm thinking something as simple as using WP E-Commerce could do the job.  I just create a catalog of high resolution images, and add a link to the product page on the blog post.

Can you see that working?

Comment: I'd note that this is very close to a plugin recomendation question, a kind of question which does not fit into the format of this site, and would be closed

Comment: I like plugin recommendation questions and answers. The best way to help new people learn. Too bad WP Answers frowns on these type of questions nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Use any E-Commerce plugin.

Which you use is up to you, pretty much all of them do the job. Create a product for your image, set the low res image as the featured image, or some content imag, then set it up as a digital/download product with the file being the original high resolution image.

How you would do this would depend on the plugin used. Which you use I will not go into as that is a job for another question ( and such a question would be a plugin recommendation question **which would be offtopic, and closed by moderation** )

Answer (score 0):

Because of the financial hassle of selling from your own website (credit card transactions, paypal, whatnot), I decided to upload my photo's to 500px.com and use the store functionality they provide. You get paid for each download or canvas ordered through there website. This might not be what you are looking for, but I still wanted to throw this in, as an option ;-).

Cheers,

J.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NextGEN Gallery here is a free extension for selling photos:

- [NextGEN Gallery Sell Photo](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery-sell-photo/)

Answer (score -1):

Plugins:

- [WP iSell Photo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-isell-photo/)
- [Image Store](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-store/)

Comment: Funny, a downvote because I gave a recommendation of a plugin, which is exactly what the question asker wanted... But wait, WP Answers doesn't like "recommendations".